# How to insert break tags after non terminal dots in raw html text nodes, using regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that matches all points that aren't between quotes and aren't followed by a '<'.

This is to parse text to ssml (Speech Synthesis Markup Language). The regex will be used to automatically add `<break time="200ms"/>` after a point.

I already have created a pattern that matches all points that aren't between quotes:

```
/\.(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)/g
```

The above regex gives following output: (^ = match)

```
This. is.a.<break time="0.5s"/> test sentence.
    ^   ^ ^                                  ^
```

But the regex I'm trying to create shouldn't match the third point.
Matches should be as following:

```
This. is.a.<break time="0.5s"/> test sentence.
    ^   ^                                    ^
```

Anyone who can help me out?

Comment: I think you may simplify the task a bit: first just replace all substrings that start and end with quotes, then count (or do anything you need) with points, like this: `'This. is.a.<break time="0.5s"/> test sen"tence.'.replace(/".*?"/g, '')`

Comment: Perhaps you tell us what you are trying to do? For example if it is live HTML, you can to textContent which will ignore tags

Comment: The thing is I still need the substrings that start and end with quotes. For example, I can't remove the '0.5s' between the two quotes.

Comment: @mplungjan : I updated my question to make it clear what I'm trying to accomplish here.

Comment: What platform are you using? node.js? Browser?

Comment: I'm using the Ionic 4 framework which is build on Angular 7.

Comment: I have added that tag

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with ionic, it's only js/regexp related, so I think the tag is irrelevant. There is a fully working solution below (second snippet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation group capture can help.

You can consume or even capture the string expressions as long as you capture the dots in another group:

```
/((?:[^"\.]|(?:"(?:\\\\|\\"|[^"])*"))*)(\.(?!\s*<))((?:[^"\.]|(?:"(?:\\\\|\\"|[^"])*"))*)/g
```

`[^"\.]` means any char other than dot or double quote.

`"(?:\\\\|\\"|[^"])*"` means a string expression (possibly containing escaped double quotes or dots)

So `(?:[^"\.]|"(?:\\\\|\\"|[^"])*")*` will consume all chars except dots (`.`), ignoring the dots inside string expressions, as far as possible.

When executing this regexp on this string:

```
"Thi\\\"s." is..a.<break time="0\".5s"/> test sentence.
```

will generate these matches:

### Match1

- Full match, from char 0 to 15: `"Thi\\\"s." is.`
- Group 1., from char 14 to 15: `.`

### Match 2

- Full match, from char 15 to 16: `.`
- Group 1., from char 15 to 16: `.`

### Match 3

- Full match, from char 18 to 55: `<break time="0\".5s"/> test sentence.`
- Group 1. from char 54 to 55: `.`

You can test it with [this wonderful tool](https://regex101.com/)

The way the expression is written, the captured point will always be in the second group, so the index of the dot will be `match.index` + `group[1].length`, if `group[1] exists`.

**Note:** the given expression accounts for escaped double quotes, otherwise the solution would fail when encountering some.

Summarized working solution below:

```js
// g is needed to collect all matches
const regexp = /((?:[^"\.]|(?:"(?:\\\\|\\"|[^"])*"))*)(\.(?!\s*<))((?:[^"\.]|(?:"(?:\\\\|\\"|[^"])*"))*)/g;

function getMatchedPointsNotFollowedByChevronAndOutsideOfStrings(input) {
  let match;
  const result = [];

  // reset the regexp lastIndex because we're
  // re-using it at each call
  regexp.lastIndex = 0;
 
  while ((match = regexp.exec(input))) {
      // index of the dot is the match index +
      // the length of group 1 if present
      result.push(match.index + (match[1] ? match[1].length : 0));
  }

  // the result now contains the indices of all '.'
  // conforming to the rule we chose
  return result;
}

// Escaping escaped string is tricky, proof as console.log
const testString = `"Thi\\\\\\"s." is..a.<break time="0\\".5s"/> test sentence.`;
console.log(testString);

// final result
console.log(
    getMatchedPointsNotFollowedByChevronAndOutsideOfStrings(testString)
);
```

**edit:**

The OP actually wants to add pause markup after points in text as a raw html string.

Fully working solution:

```js
// g is needed to collect all matches
const regexp = /((?:[^"\.]|(?:"(?:\\\\|\\"|[^"])*"))*)(\.(?!\s*<))((?:[^"\.]|(?:"(?:\\\\|\\"|[^"])*"))*)/g;

function addPauses(input) {
    let match;
    const dotOffsets = [];

    // reset the regexp lastIndex because we're
    // re-using it at each call
    regexp.lastIndex = 0;
    const ts = Date.now();

    // first collect all points offsets
    while ((match = regexp.exec(input))) {
        // offset of the dot is the match index + the length of first group if present
        dotOffsets.push(match.index + (match[1] ? match[1].length : 0));
    }

    // no points found, we can return the input as it is
    if (dotOffsets.length === 0) {
        return input;
    }

    // there are points, reconstruct the string with a break added after each
    const reduction = dotOffsets.reduce(
        (res, offset, index) => {
            // a segment is a substring of the input from a point
            // to the next (from 0 before the first point)
            const segment = input.substring(
              index <= 0 ? 0 : dotOffsets[index - 1] + 1,
              offset + 1
            );
            return `${res}${segment}<break time="200ms"/>`;
        },
        ''
    );

    // adding the last segment from the last point to the end of the string
    const rest = input.substring(dotOffsets[dotOffsets.length - 1] + 1);
    return `${reduction}${rest}`;
}

const testString = `
<p>
    This is a sample from Wikipedia.
    It is used as an example for this snippet.
</p>
<p>
    <b>Hypertext Markup Language</b> (<b>HTML</b>) is the standard
    <a href="/wiki/Markup_language.html" title="Markup language">
        markup language
    </a> for documents designed to be displayed in a
    <a href="/wiki/Web_browser.html" title="Web browser">
        web browser
    </a>.
    It can be assisted by technologies such as
    <a href="/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets" title="Cascading Style Sheets">
        Cascading Style Sheets
    </a>
    (CSS) and
    <a href="/wiki/Scripting_language.html" title="Scripting language">
        scripting languages
    </a>
    such as
    <a href="/wiki/JavaScript.html" title="JavaScript">JavaScript</a>.
</p>
`;


console.log(`Initial raw html:\n${testString}\n`);

console.log(`Result (added 2 pauses):\n${addPauses(testString)}\n`);
```